# Partial Dependence Plot interpretation

Tags: partial-plot

This question is regarding the partial dependence plots obtained from a Random Forest model. I am trying to do classification modelling. I see negative values in the $y$-axis.

[image]

How to interpret this?

Comment: It would help if you posted the plot in question

Comment: I have updated the picture. Sorry i dont have good quality picture.

Comment: It could be outputting the probabilities on the log odds scale. What software are you using?

Comment: @DexGroves my money is on R: [`randomForest::partialPlot()`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-12/topics/partialPlot)

Comment: see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/139756/56940) for a similar question.

Answer (score 7):

If this came from R, then these are *logits* of probabilities, not raw probabilities.

As per the documentation:

> The function being plotted is defined as: $$\tilde{f}(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x, x_{iC}),$$ where $x$ is the variable for which partial dependence is sought, and $x_{iC}$ is the other variables in the data. The summand is the predicted regression function for regression, and logits (i.e., log of fraction of votes) for which.class for classification: $$f(x) = \log p_k(x) - \frac{1}{K} \sum_{j=1}^K \log p_j(x),$$ where $K$ is the number of classes, $k$ is `which.class`, and $p_j$ is the proportion of votes for class $j$.

*(http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-12/topics/partialPlot)*

It is perfectly fine to have negative values, or for that matter values greater than 1. Recall what the [logit function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) looks like:

[image]

*(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit#/media/File:Logit.svg)*

Negative values correspond to probabilities (or in this case proportions) less than 0.5.